How to ensure pixel perfect layout in Flutter
We are developing a flutter app which supports multiple languages. The client wants the app to look exactly the same on all phones like the Figma design given to us. They have sent us screenshots of the Figma design, Android and iOS phones by putting them side to side. They have drawn red straight lines to show the differences in the layout. For an example - see below:

The issues they have with this are:
1 & 2 - the gap is not the same.
3 & 4 - the bottom button is not in the same vertical position
5, 6 & 7 - the star icon is not the same in all three
8, 9, & 10 - the heading is not the same position as all three.
My question is
1 - is it possible to ensure IDENTICAL vertical position across all phones and both operating systems - regardless of the default font size of the user's phone and the operating system of user's phone as well as across all languages.
2 - If yes, what is the method to achieve this?

Think about it logically. You would need to start with the smallest device... layout the design with every language you expect to use... adjust the layout and text line-breaks so the longest strings fit the same vertical spacing... then define a "fixed-size" rectangle that fits that layout and center it on every device: https://i.sstatic.net/EvrBfDZP.png --- do you think that is what your client wants?

@DonMag - no they want the entire screen to be filled up

@Vinayak -- so, how can you fill the entire screen of different size devices, while still having it look "IDENTICAL"? That makes no sense.

You'll have to tinker a lot on different targets to ensure this. Flutter renders its Widgets differently on different platforms, mostly in terms of padding and margin, so I had to have conditional padding values for each platform through trial and error. Not to mention that logical sizes differ from physical sizes due to pixel density. My Android phone is bigger in physical size than my iPhone but can display less content than my iPhone

@DonMag I wrote to my client saying that it is not possible but they are insistent - so I thought I will ask if there is any possible way to achieve this

@Vinayak - one can make a layout look balanced on different screen sizes. Maybe slightly different font sizes... maybe a little extra vertical spacing between elements... maybe a little extra padding on the sides. Obviously, though, a layout on an iPhone Pro Max at 420x932 resolution cannot look IDENTICAL on an iPhone SE at 375x667. That's just common sense.

There are multiple method to implement to achieve responsive screen

Use of MediaQuery
double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

Container(
  width: screenWidth * 0.8, // 80% of the screen width
  height: screenHeight * 0.2, // 20% of the screen height
);


Use Layout Builder


    LayoutBuilder(
       builder: (context, constraints) {
         double maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth;
          return maxWidth > 600
            ? Text("Large Screen Layout")
             : Text("Small Screen Layout");
       },
    );


Use of Expanded and Flexible

Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Container(color: Colors.red),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Container(color: Colors.blue),
    ),
  ],
);


Use of pre defined packages

flutter_screenutil:  [Helps scale widgets and fonts based on screen dimensions]
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';

ScreenUtil.init(context, designSize: Size(360, 690));

Container(
  width: 100.w, 
  height: 50.h, 
);

responsive_framework:  [Automatically adapts to different screen sizes and breakpoints]
MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, child) => ResponsiveWrapper.builder(
    child,
    maxWidth: 1200,
    minWidth: 480,
    defaultScale: true,
    breakpoints: [
      ResponsiveBreakpoint.resize(480, name: MOBILE),
      ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(800, name: TABLET),
      ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(1200, name: DESKTOP),
    ],
  ),
);

sizer:  [For easy sizing of widgets and text.]
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';

Sizer(
  builder: (context, orientation, deviceType) {
    return Container(
      width: 80.w, // Percentage width
      height: 20.h, // Percentage height
    );
  },
);

